# Crystal Report not getting exact decimal values as in DB

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report XI, I have created a report whose data source is a stored procedure.

Stored procedure getting correct values, but in crystal report's field is different. The value in stored procedure is : 43,859.92. But in crystal report is : 43,859.90.
I have format the field in crystal report use format field -> decimals : 1.00, rounding : 0.01.
I can't change values to string in store procedure as I need it for further calculations.

My required is exactly the DB data. Any suggestion?

Comment: you convert into string in stored procedure and when it comes to crystal report you can again convert it back into number using `ToNumber`. Try this way.

Comment: @Siva, Thanks for your suggestion. But, there are a lot of report, so I want only change one side (crystal report), because the problem is in the crystal report.

Comment: ok then can you just pick the query from crystal report and fire on database and check what is the format of that column?

Comment: The format of the column is number.

Comment: To the extent I understand the input to the crystal reports is a number value that is rounded...in this case nothing much can be done.. until and unless you get as it is number to the crystal

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your number: 43,859.92, even tried adding 22 at the end (43,859.9222) and in Crystal Reports chose the same options as you did, decimals 1.00, rounding 0.01 and got good number, so 43,859.92.
   When I set rounding to 0.1 I got the same bad number as you got, so 43,859.90.
   Please check again, I believe your rounding is wrong, it needs to be 0.01, it is possible you have set it to 0.1. If that isn't the case, and your rounding is really set to 0.01, then try to set it lower, so 0.001.